# ImportError: No module named readability

Tags: python, readability

i install python readability from : https://github.com/buriy/python-readability

i can use:

```
python -m readability.readability -u http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readability-lxml
```

but when i use in readability.py and run this with python command:

```
from readability.readability import Document
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

in .py file show error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "readability.py", line 1, in 
>       from readability.readability import Document ImportError: No module named readability

Comment: Did you name your script `readability` too?

Comment: in repo help:
pip install readability-lxml
and use this module

Comment: That's not what was asked. What is the name of the script file that you are running your code from?

Comment: my file name is readability.py and run python readability.py

Comment: Don't name the script the same thing as a module you are going to use, that is why the import is confused!

Comment: very thanks, it resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to import your file. Simply rename it.

> File "**readability.py**", line 1, in from
>   readability.readability import Document
>   ImportError: No module named readability

Answer (score 6):

I know is late to comment a solution, but in case someone need it like me minutes ago..

In python3 try install readability-lxml with

```
$ pip3 install readability-lxml
```

It works form me